# IdentityServer4 Creating Access Token From External Provider

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using IdentityServer4 with External Providers (Google Auth). How do I generate an Access Token based on successfully logging in with Google? I would like to inject my own claims.

Answer (score 0):

If implementing external login(Google Auth) in Identity Server , after Identity server receive id token from external provider , it will decode the token and get user's claims , sign in user , then create identity server's own tokens and at last return to your client app .

If you want to add custom cliams to access token which issued by Identity Server , youc can implement [IProfileService](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html) :

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public MyProfileService()
    { }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {

        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {

            new Claim("TestKey", "TestValue")
        };
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        // await base.IsActiveAsync(context);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register in DI :

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, MyProfileService>();
```

Comment: I understand the ProfileService but I don't understand where or when the new Access Token get's created. I would assume in the Callback from Google, and if so how?

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to ask the right questions when you don't quite understand how it works. My flow consist of: Client App calls into my ID4 server that redirects the user to the Google login. I successfully login and get redirect to the External Callback method. From there I would like inject my own claims and issue an Access Token back to the Client app. I would like to accomplish this in a single round trip from the Client App.

Comment: @JohnRowland  ,in  External Callback method IDS4 will get claims from external identity provider and issue authentication cookie for user , but it will redirect to a callback url where ids4 middleware will continue handle the tokens , the token services are registered in AddIdentityServer and not expose , but all the logic are  in identity server side and is "in a single round trip from the Client App". You can use exposed services/events to customize the behavior like `IProfileService`